# cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I am building my own first Gem. After I created some functionality I ordered all the files like to the best practice of gem building.

I moved all the files to right folders.
The executable is in `bin/boss-mailer`, the rest is put all in the `lib` folder like:

[image]

The executable is simple. I just set the executable to ruby and try to require the `boss_mailer.rb` in the lib file.

[image]

This cannot load my file. I can require it by using `require "./boss_mailer"` beginning to pointing the current path.
**But** in other Gems on Github I see that people just use `require "filename"` to reference to loading file. Like here: [gli gem](https://github.com/davetron5000/gli/blob/gli-2/bin/gli)

#### My Question

Do I have to pre-build the gem or something else to require my files without to point to the current path?
What do I have to do require the file `lib/boss_mailer'` without using `./`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [Bundler](http://bundler.io/)? I would recommend that. Then running your binary would be simply as:

```
bundle exec ./bin/boss_mailer.rb
```

Please make sure that you configure the `$LOAD_PATH` correctly in your `boss-mailer.gemspec` correctly, but if you've followed the best practices you've probably already done that.

Comment: oh my took me longer to write this question than the time this answer came in.
I just executed the file without bundler.

`bundle exec bin/boss_mailer` done all the thing. Thank you very much!

Comment: A well asked question answers itself :)